# UFT - Select File from TreeView

Tags: hp-uft

I have recorded a script to Click on an XML file(highlight, right-click and open) from a popup treeview, the popup contains a number of files(varying amounts/types and they can appear in any order), the one I will always want to select always begins with 'AB', the numerics of the filename will change per test however:

```
SwfWindow("APPMAIN").SwfWindow("2000HOME").SwfTreeView("MainTreeList").SelectCell "AB99872","Object Name"

SwfWindow("APP-MAIN").SwfToolbar("SwfToolbar").Select "Open"
```

After Recording, I run the script, but I get the following error:

> SelectCell :SelectCell :Cannot identify the specified item = AB99872 of the TreeView.

So my question is 2 part:

1. Why can it not select the file *AB99872* after the initial record using `SelectCell`?
2. Considering that the filename will change per test(ie... *AB**), what is the best way to automate this to be robust enough to select any Filename beginning with 'AB'. I did try UI Automation/Object Recognition and I used a regular expression like ^AB.* but UFT(v12.54) continually crashed with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tree's [`GetContent`](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/WindowsForms/SWFPACKAGELib~SwfTreeView.html#GetContent) method and then use regular expressions to find the name of the node to select (then use that value in `SelectCell`.

Comment: Thanks, so I tried:   msgbox SwfWindow("APPMAIN").SwfWindow("2000HOME").SwfTreeView("MainTreeList").GetContent     This returns a blank msgbox popup. I did try GetVisibleText however and that returns ALL text on the current window in the msgbox popup, not sure if that will help but I'll do some rework with it.

Comment: With the GetVisibleText data, is there a method I can use to search through the nodes to find the matching data, i.e. a filename that is something like '^AB*'  ...... Thanks

Comment: @CodeSpy, I'm not familiar with `SwfTreeView` I just looked at the documentation, perhaps you can use `GetItem` or `GetItemProperty`